# material UI: sx prop how to manage diplay none on some condition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In MUI v5 I have

```
<Box sx={{ display: 'none'}}>
  Print Only (Hide on screen only)
</Box>
```

In the above, I want to add some conditions for `none` like below. Not getting the right syntax on how to do this. the below is not working

```
<Box sx={{ display: value !== index ? 'none' : 'block' }}>
  Print Only (Hide on screen only)
</Box>
```

Comment: Will this work `{
value == index ? <Box>
  Print Only (Hide on screen only)
</Box> : <></>
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1:

```js
<Box 
 sx={{
   ...(value !== index && {
        display: "none"
   }),
 }}
>
  Print Only (Hide on screen only)
</Box>
```

#### Option 2:

```js
const display = value !== index ? "none" : "block"

<Box
 display={display}
>
  Print Only (Hide on screen only)
</Box>
```

Comment: Option 1 is what is was looking for